# Python Running SQL Query With Temp Tables

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I am new to the Python-SQL connectivity world. My goal is to retrieve data from SQL in a pandas DataFrame format by executing long SQL queries thru my python script.

Most of my SQL queries are long with multiple interim-temp tables before the final SELECT statement from the last temp table. When I run such a monolithic query in Python I get an error saying -

> "pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql"

Though they run absolutely fine in MS SQL Management Studio

I suspect this is due to the interim-temp tables, because if I split my long query into two pieces (with everything before the final `SELECT` in 1st section and final `SELECT` in the 2nd section) the two section sequentially, run fine

**Can someone guide me why is it so or alternatively what is the best way to run long queries with temp tables/views and retrieve results in a pandas DataFrame?**

Here is my sample Python code that ideally should take a fine name as an input and run the SQL to retrieve results in a data frame, however it fails in case of a query with temp tables

```
import pyodbc as db
import pandas as pd
filename = 'file.sql'
username = 'XXXX'
password = 'YYYYY'
driver= '{ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}' 
database = 'DB'
server = 'local'
conn = db.connect('DRIVER='+driver+'; PORT=1433; SERVER='+server+'; 
PORT=1443; DATABASE='+database+'; UID='+username+'; PWD='+ password)
fd = open(filename, 'r')
sqlfile = fd.read()
fd.close()

sqlcommand1 = sql
df_table = pd.read_sql(sqlcommand1, conn)
```

If I break my sql query in two pieces (one with all temp tables and 2nd with final `Select`), then it runs fine. Below is a modified function that splits the long Query after finding '/**/' and it works fine

```
"""
This Function Reads a SQL Script From an Extrenal File and Executes The 
Script in SQL. If The SQL Script Has Bunch of Tem Tables/Views
Followed By a Select Statement to Retrieve Data From Those Views Then Input 
SQL File Should Have '/**/' Immediately Before the Final
Select Statement. This is to Esnure Final Select Statement is Executed on 
the Temporary Views Already Run by Python. 
Input is a SQL File Name and Output is a DataFrame
"""

import pyodbc as db
import pandas as pd
filename = 'filename.sql'
username = 'XXXX'
password = 'YYYYY'
driver= '{ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}' 
database = 'DB'
server = 'local'
conn = db.connect('DRIVER='+driver+'; PORT=1433; SERVER='+server+'; 
PORT=1443; DATABASE='+database+'; UID='+username+'; PWD='+ password)
fd = open(filename, 'r')
sqlfile = fd.read()
fd.close()

sql = sqlfile.split('/**/')

sqlcommand1 = sql[0] #1st Section of Query with temp tables
sqlcommand2 = sql[1] #2nd section of Query with final SELECT statement
conn.execute(sqlcommand1)
df_table = pd.read_sql(sqlcommand2, conn)
```

Comment: The information needed to debug this is the query itself, more so than all the setup stuff.

Comment: Multiple statements are not supported in `read_sql`. Consider saving lines in a stored procedure where you then can call it in `read_sql` assuming stored proc returns a resultset.

Answer (score 5):

**Quick and dirty answer:** if using T-SQL put the line `SET NOCOUNT ON` at the beginning of your query.

Like @Parfait mentioned above the pandas `read_sql` method can only support one result set. However, when you generate a temp table in T-sql you do create a result set in the form "(XX row(s) affected)" which is what causes your original query to fail. By setting `NOCOUNT` you eliminate any early returns and only get the results from your final `SELECT` statement.

Alternatively, if using pyodbc cursor instead of pandas you can utilize `nextset()` to skip the result sets from the temp table(s). More info on pyodbc [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor).